# Is there a way to use array of strings as variable names with destructuring assignment? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

Let's remember, how the usual destructuring assignment works with arrays:

```js
const numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
[one, two, three] = numbers;
console.log(`${one} ${two} ${three}`);
```

But what if we have long arrays of data, for example with 20 items? It doesn't seem good to list them manually as in example above. Is there a way to extract an array of strings via destructuring assignment and use the strings as values?

Pseudo code:

```
let numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
[...numbers] = numbers;
```

Expected result:

```
console.log(one); // 'one'
console.log(two); // 'two'
console.log(three); // 'three'
```

I feel that it isn't designed for such cases, am I right?

Comment: Yep, it would totally break in the values not having valid characters for naming variables (like whitespace and reserved symbols). Example: `numbers = [ 'a number', 'another-number']`

Comment: @OsmanCea Both examples you show are perfectly valid property names in Javascript.

Comment: yes, they're valid as key names in objects, but not as standalone variables, which is what OP is suggesting

Comment: @connexo They are valid strings (and hence valid object keys), but they are not valid identifiers. `console.log(a number);` is absolutely a syntax error.

Comment: That would be interesting, but can't remember or imagine doing so for twenty variables. If there are twenty items in your list, it's probably the best to keep it like that. Can you show a single use case where this functionality would be awesome?

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli, I think that *"awesome"* is not the right word, because we can alternatively use array or object for that, but using arrays is not very comfortable in some cases, and if to use an object, we should firstly create it and fill up with all fields. I think that described functionality would be useful when we're working with Angular and D3, and have many properties to work with. For example, we want to create 3 different line charts, which should have a bunch of repeated properties, so we can keep them as array of strings separately, and then get and store as class properties.

Comment: If there are common set of properties for multiple objects, and they are stored as an array, the easiest way I know is to reduce it to object like this `pList.reduce((o, p) => ({...o, [p]: p}), {})`. So basically what you want is shorter and cleaner syntax to do this, am I right? However these properties are packed as one object, they are not independent variables. That's why I wanted know what is the meaning in creating so many independent variables, as in your example, that current destructuring syntax would be too long to do that.

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli, yes, as I said, *we can* work with objects, but it would be great to have an option to work with object properties and set them like `this[...arr] = anotherArr`. I can't imagine other good usecases, but it doesn't mean, that they don't exist.

Comment: You can't access array without index but you can use this using for loop and after that check the condition